# Mediatr IPipelineBehavior not triggered

Tags: c#, unity-container, mediatr

I have implemented `Mediatr` in my `.NET framework` project and would like to use a `IPipelineBehavior`.

I have implemented and registered the container using the example from the project: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/samples/MediatR.Examples.Unity/Program.cs

This is my Behavior

```
public class AuditPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    {
        private readonly ILeaveAuditTrail _auditor;

        public AuditPipelineBehavior(ILeaveAuditTrail auditor)
        {
            _auditor = auditor;
        }
        public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
        {
            if (AuditPrevented(request))
                return await next();

            var response = await next();
            var auditLog = _auditor.CreateAuditLog(request, response);
            //Dispatch audit

            return response;
        }

        private static bool AuditPrevented<TInput>(TInput query)
        {
            return query.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PreventAuditAttribute), true).Any();
        }
    }
```

And i register is like this together with my Mediatr

```
container.RegisterMediator(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterMediatorHandlers(applicationAssembly);
            container.RegisterType(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(AuditPipelineBehavior<,>));
            container.RegisterType<ILeaveAuditTrail, DefaultAuditor>();
```

When i send the IRequest with Mediatr it is handled fine and i get the results but the AuditPipeline is not called.

If i remove the `async` keyword and just return `next();` It works. But this way i cannot correctly intercept my response.

Also on the example Github the handle is implemented async: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Behaviors

Answer (score 1):

The issue was not related to the registration of `Mediatr`or the `PipelineBehavior`.

When calling the `mediator.Send()`method it was not in an async method. `.Result`was used instead of `await`. Because of this the handling of the pipeline only worked when the `async`keyword was not present.

Make sure to never use the `.Result` to chain these async calls. Mark the controller method `async` and await the `mediator.Send()`